# Spring: Why is it bad to return a whole OAuth2User in an endpoint?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm building an OAuth2 authenticated app using Spring Boot, following this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

At one point, the endpoint /user sends back the currently logged in user.

The guide warns by saying:

> "It’s not a great idea to return a whole OAuth2User in an endpoint since it might contain information you would rather not reveal to a browser client."

But it doesn't give any more information - what type of information should I not be revealing to a browser client?

Thanks!

Comment: it could be anything that is sensitive. What if you have password hashes on your user object, then someone could take those and try to crack them offline, or credit card numbers in your user object etc.

Answer (score 2):

In Spring Security 5.x, the `OAuth2User` is a specific `OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal` (very similar to a [`UserDetails`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-userdetails) but without any notion of a password). Even without a password, exposing it can (and often will) leak sensitive information, implementation details of your authentication scheme, etc. You can expose it if you choose, but the warning in the guide is suggesting that care should be taken so as not to expose anything considered sensitive, and you should consider alternatives before exposing it directly.

For example, you might consider creating a `CustomUser` class that is populated from claims on the `OAuth2User` using a custom `OAuth2UserService` (various examples in the [advanced configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#oauth2login-advanced) section of the docs). You can also take various steps to decouple the representation of an oauth2 user in Spring Security from the representation of a user in your application (e.g. by using [@AuthenticationPrincipal](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#mvc-authentication-principal) to resolve your own custom user or access claims). If the application itself does not need a custom user, you can simply map claims of the `OAuth2User` to a response in your custom endpoint, as demonstrated in the guide.

Finally, you can combine all of these techniques to make your `/user` endpoint a "one liner" again, as in:

```java
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "customUser")
public @interface CurrentUser {}
```

```java
@GetMapping("/user")
public CustomUser user(@CurrentUser CustomUser customUser) {
    return customUser;
}
```